# Magento 2: Shipping method radio button is disabled

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, magento-2.1.3

In checkout page of Magento 2, all enabled shipping method radio buttons are showing as disabled. Anybody have faced such an issue?

I used latest version: 2.1.3

Comment: Sometimes i notice this happening on my dev server

Comment: It is a Magento bug - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7497

Answer (score 0):

**Override** Module

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/block-loader.js
To Magento Theme . Ex.: magento_root/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Ui/web/js/block-loader.js

In :

```
function removeBlockLoader(element) {...}
```

Alter to :

```
function removeBlockLoader(element) {
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!element.has(blockLoaderClass).length) {
        return;
    }
    element.find(blockLoaderClass).remove();
    element.find('input:not("._disabled"), select:not("._disabled")').prop('disabled', false);
    element.find('input:disabled, select:disabled').removeClass('_disabled');
    element.removeClass(blockContentLoadingClass);
}, 100);
}
```

After run:

```
magento setup:upgrade

magento setup:di:compile 

magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
```